# Javascript regex, wont match words next to html tag

Tags: javascript, regex, spell-checking, pspell

I'm using the jquery spellchecker plugin on a contenteditable div, which inserts divs and brs on return. The spellchecker's regex won't match an incorrectly spelled word which is next to a tag. Here is the contents of div i'm performing the regex on:

```
Praesent commodo cursus magna,
<br>
<br>
dsf
<br>
vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.
```

Here is the javascript, which is in a loop, and 'replaceWord' is an incorrectly spelled word:

```
var re = new RegExp('(^|[^a-zA-Z])(' + replaceWord + ')([^a-zA-Z]|$)', 'g');
html = html.replace(re, '$1<span class="spellcheck-word-highlight">$2</span>$3');
```

The regex correctly matches all other words though.
Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you put a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo?

Comment: And which word is incorrectly spelled in your example? I tried to replace "dsf" and "vel" - regexp is working fine.

Comment: FYI the "\b" marker matches the "boundary" of a word ...

Comment: is it possible that replaceWord contains characters that have special meaning inside of regular expressions?  What do you mean by "The regex correctly matches all other words though" ?

Comment: I don't understand why your spellchecker involves HTML markup...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try:

```
var re = new RegExp('\\b(' + replaceWord + ')\\b', 'g');
```

instead.  The "\b" qualifier (backslash doubled in the strings above) matches the transition from non-word character (or beginning of text) to word character, and word character to non-word character (or end of text).